# Copy one struct object

Tags: swift, struct

i have to quite similar struct objects. but one includes more values than the other. As the initial is required for KituraKuery methods i can not modify it but require more information for future processing.

my problem is now, that these struct objects look like this:

```
struct provider: Codable {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email:String?
}
extension provider: Model{
    class Persistence {}
}

struct provider2: Codable {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email:String?
    var providerCategories: [categories]?
}
extension provider: Model{
    class Persistence {}
}
```

what i need is basically a smarter way to copy information from provider to provider2.

what i did as of now is i provided an init to provider2 taking provider as input and adding all values to it.

```
struct provider2: Codable {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email:String?
    var providerCategories: [categories]?

    init(provider: provider?) {
        if let provider = provider{
            firstName = provider.firstName
            lastName = provider.lastName
            email = provider.lastName
        }
    }
extension provider: Model{
    class Persistence {}
}
```

i however believe this is probably the worst way and there are much better and more lean approaches to it.

I tried myself on protocols but could that not really get to work.

Any input would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach both Provider and Provider2 struct are tightly coupled to each other. So lets say in future if you want to change Provider struct or you want to initialise Provider2 struct with another struct, then you need to change lot of things.
We can solve the problem easily by decoupling both Provider and Provider2 struct

```
protocol BasicInfo {
    var firstName: String? { get set }
    var lastName: String? { get set }
    var email:String? { get set }
}

protocol Address {
    var address: String? {get set}
}

struct Provider: BasicInfo {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email: String?
}

struct Provider2: BasicInfo, Address {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email:String?
    var address: String?

    init(basic: BasicInfo, add: String) {
        firstName = basic.firstName
        lastName = basic.lastName
        email = basic.email
        address = add
    }
}

//Below are instances of respective struct
let provider1 = Provider(firstName: "Test1", lastName: "TestLast1", email: "test1@gmail.com")
var provider2 = Provider2(basic: provider1, add: "Germany")
```

In above code i have two different Struct Provider and Provider2. Provider2 contains more variable than Provider (i have just added a single var to demonstrate). Now lets say in future we don't require Provider to fill Provider2, we have a new struct Provider3 which will fill Provider2 values.

```
struct Provider3: BasicInfo {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email: String?
    var middleName: String? //new property added
}

//Below are instances of respective struct
let provider3 = Provider3(firstName: "Test1", lastName: "TestLast1", email: "test1@gmail.com")
var provider2 = Provider2(basic: provider3, add: "Germany")
```

As you see there is no changes in struct Provider2, we have just introduce a new struct, create instance of new struct and passed that instance to Provider2 init method.

Comment: Ok, this is also my initial approach basically have a protocol that mirrors provider one and having a secon dstruct provider two that inerhits also that protocol . leading also to the init command solution i have currently.

Comment: Do we really need to creat redundant data for both struct I feel provider2 struct just have different variables and a variable of provider struct.

Comment: var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email:String?   is all the same only difference is var providerCategories: [categories]?

Comment: Yes, struct Provider2 must have a var provider: Provider, var providerCategories: [categories]?. Instead of same var firstName: String? var lastName: String? var email:String?

Comment: Mh ok but then i am doing additional nesting which i also have to change then later in my frontend as i currently use the structure from provider 1.  ... so there is no way where i could remain the previous structure and just have one more var in it .

Answer (score 0):

You could use extensions for this:

```
extension provider {
    func asProvider2() -> provider2 {
        return provider2(firstName: firstName, 
                          lastName: lastName, 
                          email: email, 
                          providerCategories: nil)
    }
}

// Then you can use it like this:
let bar = provider(firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar", email: "baz")
let bar2 = bar.asProvider2()
```

Comment: Ok but in the end i still have to type all variables again and define provider 2 entirely.I clearly like your solution more :)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you say. If you declare that extension, whenever you have a provider you can get a provider2 from it with `.asProvider2()`

Comment: I however still need to completely specify provider2 as well same as i have to specify provider1 while both only have a difference of 1 variable

Comment: so you don't want to keep the two types? how do you get the categories?

Comment: What i basically do is i create a struct that i use for a SQL call with kuery so it need to represent the DB Table structure. but now i want to enhance the data in the struct. if i add any variable the Kuery call provider1.findAll() fails . so i have to create a second struct  which is provider 2 .. but i cant feed the results easily from provider 1 to provider 2 and i actually do not want to create struct again which is mainly similar to provider1